# How do I learn Python 2 if I already know Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have some knowledge of Python 3 (I'm not a beginner, but I'm not an expert). I'm interested in web development, so I want to use Django. What are the differences between the two versions of Python? How should I switch from 3 to 2.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't so different. Almost everything you learned in Python 3 will transfer to Python 2. I would suggest that you simply dive in. Occasionally you'll see an error message, but most of the time they'll be self-explanatory.

My bet is that learning Django will be way harder than getting used to Python 2.

You might find the [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) library helpful if you want to write code that is robustly backwards-compatible. Otherwise, I can only think of two things that might be important to know in advance as you go backwards to Python 2:

1. Avoid using old-style classes. In Python 3, you can declare a class like this, without any problem:

   ```
   class Foo:
       pass
   ```

   In Python 2, if you do that, you get an old-style class, which you probably don't want. But you won't get any error messages about this, so subtle inheritance bugs might arise and stay hidden for a long time before causing problems. So in Python 2, remember to explicitly inherit from `object`:

   ```
   class Foo(object):
       pass
   ```
2. Avoid using `range(n)`, at least for large values of `n`. In Python 3, `range` returns an intelligent iterator, but in Python 2, `range` returns an actual list. For large ranges, it can burn up a lot of memory. To get the behavior of Python 3's `range` in Python 2, use `xrange(n)`. Similar caveats apply to dictionary `keys()`, `values()`, and `items()` methods. They all return lists in Python 2. Use the `iterkeys()`, `itervalues()`, and `iteritems()` methods to save memory.

There are several other excellent answers to this question that cover a few other details, such as [`unicode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8965264/577088) support.

Comment: Thanks. I probably would have made that mistake without ever realizing it.

Answer (score 5):

If you already are familiar with Python 3, then there are almost *no* differences you will have to worry about when coding in Python 2. The most user-visible differences have to do with details of the `print` statement, which you probably won't be using for Django anyway.

So, just write code, and ask about any *specific* problems you might encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Another big difference is how Python 3 handles unicode - everything in Python 3 is either a unicode string or binary data, whereas in Python 2 a distinction was made between unicode strings and 8-bit strings.

The following page has a lot more info on the difference between Python 2 and 3.
http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 1):

Read through this: http://python3porting.com/differences.html

Note that there are a lot of things simply removed from Python 2, like apply(), which you therefore need not to worry about.

Also, as noted by senderle, you use subclass from object (this is recommended in Python 3 as well, possibly for the reason that it actually makes a difference in Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3